# Python: Same word twice in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that stops if the same word is given twice. This code almost does the job, but it stops only if the duplicate words are given sequentially. Thanks for your help.

```
list = []
double = None
while True:
    word = input("word: ")
    lista.append(word)
    if douple == word:
        print(f"You gave {len(list)} words")
        break
    double = word
```

Comment: Try looking at a dictionary. It stores key:value pairs. And all you have to do is to see if your key exists to know if a duplicate exists.

Comment: You should try a `set()` for this. Just check if the word is in the set.

Comment: `list` is python built-in don't use it as variable.

Comment: or use `if word in list: break`

Comment: in the line `if douple == word:` you have a typo: `douple` instead of `double`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the word is already in the list

```
seen = []
while True:
    word = input("word: ")
    if word in seen:
        print(f"You gave {len(seen)} words")
        break
    seen.append(word)
```

If you just want to tell duplicates, and don't need to keep the order, you can use a `set` instead; this will be more efficient for a large number of words:

```
seen = set()
while True:
    word = input("word: ")
    if word in seen:
        print(f"You gave {len(seen)} words")
        break
    seen.add(word)
```

Finally, in sufficiently recent Python (at least 3.6 or 3.7, depending on how you take things), you can do both by using a dictionary; this is both efficient and keeps the order in which the words were entered:

```
seen = {}
while True:
    word = input("word: ")
    if word in seen:
        print(f"You gave {len(seen)} words")
        break
    seen[word] = None
```

Comment: Invalid syntax for the `break`...

Comment: Ah yes, missing `:` — fixed

Comment: No, that's not it. It's the unexpected indent.

Comment: This time for sure!

Comment: Yep, you got it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to what is given below:

```
words_list = []
while True:
    word = input("Word: ")
    if word not in words_list:    #Checks if the word is in the list. If it exists in list, it would return False
        words_list.append(word)
    else:
        print(f"You gave {len(words_list)} words")
        break
```

I have changed a few things:

1. Don't use list as a variable name as it is a keyword in Python.
2. Check for duplicate words using `not in` before you append it to the list. If word exists in the list, the loop would break.

This should do the work. You can always comment down if you need clarification or if the code dosen't work.